# Codeigniter news tutorial view method not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, mamp

Hey guys im learning codeigniter and im on the news tutorial. Im pretty much finished but my view method is showing 404 rather than the news itself. I've tried to debug with the following code

```
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($this->news_model->get_news($slug));
    exit();
```

and that returns

```
NULL
```

heres how my controller works thats calling the method

```
<?php 
class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
    }

    public function index() {

        //echo '<pre>';
        //var_dump($this->news_model->get_news());
        //exit();

        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
        $data['title'] = 'News archive';

        $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('news/index',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function view($slug) {
        //echo '<pre>';
        //var_dump($this->news_model->get_news($slug));
        //exit();
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);

        if (empty($data['news_item'])) {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];
        $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('news/view',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }

}
```

im still a beginner so my debugging solutions are limited.

Comment: Which version of CI are you using??

Comment: I think the get_news() method in your news model may be the culprit. Additionally, you should really set the $slug variable to null or some other default to prevent errors when the page is accessed without a slug.


public function view($slug = null) {
    ...
}

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju im learning thru the legacy version

Comment: Your ``if( empty`` statement is throwing 404 error. ``$data['news_item']`` is not defined

Comment: @twistedpixel i will give that a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
```

should be

```
$data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
```

according to the rest of your code.

Comment: It happens to us all :)

Comment: im able to view the article but im getting `NULL` when the page loads

Comment: What do you mean? If you can view the article, how can you be getting NULL? NULL means "completely empty; unset".

Comment: i still get the 404 so im assuming its coming from that?

Comment: and also i have moved onto laravel because documentation and tutorials are up to date rather than codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

don't use $slug, the tutorial $slug set true when you insert data from set_news but i don't understand why the attribute type varchar slug can save boolean type. Here the code to set variable $slug and all attribute to db. Here the code of controller news

```
public function set_news()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

        $data = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'slug' => $slug,
            'text' => $this->input->post('text')
        );

        return $this->db->insert('news', $data);
    }
```

edit the code of method view to

```
public function view($slug = NULL)
    {
            $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
            //echo print_r($data['news_item']['0']['title'], true);

            if (empty($data['news']))
            {
                    show_404();
            }

            $data['title'] = $data['news']['0']['title'];

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

and edit the views/news/view.php to

```
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>
    <h3><?php echo $news_item['title']; ?></h3>
    <div class="main">
            <?php echo $news_item['text']; ?>
    </div>
    <p><a href="<?php echo site_url('news/'.$news_item['slug']); ?>">View article</a></p><?php endforeach; ?>
```